# Work with context in LUIS

Tags: c#, python, node.js, azure-language-understanding

I want to know how to work with context in luis. For example if I ask for what is sales, it should maintain the sales in context, so, I if I wanna know the sales done by employee I ask like, what about Mr.XXX , so It should pick the sales by Mr.XXX, so Can any one help me that how to work with the context in luis

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as context in LUIS itself.

If you are using MS [Botframework](https://dev.botframework.com/) you may define context in your bot by using Dialogs as can be seen in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). You can also create your own implementation of `IDialog<T>` and maintain your context inside - see [example here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs/Dialogs/HotelsDialog.cs).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, but I'm not using MS Bot framework, so what do I have to do.

Comment: Please see first sentence of my answer "There is no such thing as context in LUIS itself." - and it is done on purpose - actual version of LUIS is not meant to have context.

Comment: yeah. I read your reply, I' just looking for the feature like context, I mean is something like to maintain the context is available for the luis

Comment: you mean even some service/component/anything else that is not directly part of LUIS, correct?